# Making window in pygame using NOFRAME but can't choose where it appears

Tags: python, pygame

I'm learning to program, and figured out how to use the NOFRAME flag in `pygame.display.set_mode()` which I really like, but I can't drag the window now. I can't find any mention of window position in Pygame documentation or on this site.

I just checked my version of Pygame, it's 1.9.1 but my documentation is for 1.9.2 (strange, since I got them at the same time). Not sure if this matters, trying to be thorough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: normally frame is used to drag window - if you don't have frame, then you can't drag window.

Comment: Right, the desire to drag was due to its undesirable location. Now that I can position it to my heart's content, that wont be necessary!  :+D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame` (which use `SDL 1.2`) doesn't have method to move window.

It has variable which you can use to set position before you use `set_mode()`

```
import os  

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = '50, 500'
```

but if you what change position then you have to use set it again and use `set_mode()` again.

```
import os  
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

print('pos: 50, 500')
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = '50, 500'

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300), 32, pygame.NOFRAME)
time.sleep(2)

print('pos: 500, 50')
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = '500, 50'

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300), 32, pygame.NOFRAME)
time.sleep(2)

pygame.quit()
```

---

**BTW:**

`PySDL` uses `SDL 2.0` which has [SetWindowPosition](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowPosition?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29)

`pyglet` has [pyglet.window.Window.set_location](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/window/pyglet.window.Window.html#pyglet.window.Window.set_location)

Comment: I'm not allowed to actually thank you, but your answer was extremely helpful. Alone, I'd take months or years (or probably give up!) on this. I did have to tinker with the code a bit to get it working as a standalone example. I'm actually grateful for this because, in so doing, I discovered something about using NOFRAME that was very interesting (to me at least). So I'm going to share this by asking another question and (probably) answer it myself. Since I'm going to link to your answer (this question), I'm telling you first before I mark your answer as "accepted" in case you want to

Comment: ...edit it. If not that's OK I'll just include that in my new question. I want to make my question a good one, and having a working example that can be cut and pasted I think would be helpful. Editing your answer to include a cut and paste example is totally up to you. Either way, I'm definitely going to "accept" your answer since it saved me an enormous amount of time, and also was posted very quickly.